# Automatic logging of DataMapper queries

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am working on a simple app in Sinatra with DataMapper.  I want to see the queries that DM is created for my various chained finders, etc.

I have tried:

```
DataMapper::Logger.new(STDOUT, :debug)
```

in my `configure do ... end` block in an `environment.rb` file that loads when the app is started.

I have also tried:

```
DataMapper::Logger.new('log/my-app.log', :debug)
```

Neither yields log statements from the app accessed either through a browser or through an `irb` session that requires my app.  I do see the app starting message.

I am using `rackup config.ru` to run the app locally.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that I missed a perfectly reasonable step.  You need to place the `DataMapper::Logger.new(STDOUT, :debug)` before you make the connection.  HT to @snusnu on #datamapper IRC.